# How do I install gfortran (via cygwin and etexteditor) and enable ifort under Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, cygwin

I'm a newbie in the Unix world so all this is a little confusing to me. I'm having trouble compiling some Fortran files under Cygwin on Windows XP.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Installed the [e text editor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/).
2. Installed [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) via the "automatic" option inside e text editor.
3. I need to compile some Fortran files so via the "manage bundles" option I installed the Fortran bundle as well.

However, when I select "compile single file" I get an error saying `gfortran` was missing, and then that I need to set the `TM_FORTRAN` variable to the full path of my compiler.

I tried opening a Cygwin bash shell at the path mentioned (.../bin/gfortran), but the compiler was nowhere to be found.

Can someone tell me how to install this from the Cygwin command line? Where do I need to update the `TM_FORTRAN` variable for the bundle to work?

Also, how do I change the bundle "compile" option to work with `ifort` (my native compiler) on Windows? I've read the bundle file, but it is totally incomprehensible to me. Ifort is a Windows compiler, invoked simply by `ifort filename.f90`, since it is on the Windows path.

I know this is a lot to ask of a first time user here, but I really would appreciate any time you can spare to help.

Comment: The Fortran Compiler is in the package gcc-g77 in the Cygwin installer (/bin/g77)

Comment: haven't tried but `echo $TM_FORTRAN`  and `TM_FORTRAN=WHATEVERITSHOULDBE`

Comment: @bez : Can you compile your Fortran programs from a shell (i.e. bash or zsh)? I would first get this running, and *then* see how to integrate it into the editor of your choice.

Comment: BTW: Are sure that your obscure E-editor is still maintained? The page you are linking to looks more like a site selling car insurances in Japan.

Comment: @user1934428 : Well, the OP also says that he using Windows XP. I think this is a good match to the long-time gone E-Editor (which you still may find on some shareware sites).

Answer (score 0):

Rerun the cygwin installer, and choose a Fortran compiler: gcc-g77 for the older Fortran 77, gcc4-gfortran for newer standards (Fortran 95 and parts of Fortran 2003 & 2008).

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to re-run the installer. Type in the cygwin command prompt:

apt-cyg install gcc-g77

to install the gfortran package